# Easier Way to Accept Key Presses in Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Instead of having to do something long and ugly like this:

```
    def change_variable():
        global variable
        variable+=1

    def function(var, key):
        global variable
        variable=var
        turtle.listen()
        turtle.onkey(change_variable, key)
```

Is there a way to do the following? Any modules or maybe an update I need?

```
    turtle.onkey(variable+=1, key)
```

And, in addition, being able to do the following would make things 1000x easier for me, is this possible?

```
    while 1:
        turtle.onkey(break, key)
```

Comment: What is `turtle.onkey(break, key)` supposed to do? `break` from what?

Comment: `break` from a `while` or `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a closure and consolidate the ugliness into a smaller area:

```
def function(var, key):
    def change_variable():
        nonlocal var
        var += 1
        print(var)  # just to prove it's incrementing
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onkey(change_variable, key)
```

I'm assuming the global `variable` was part of the ugliness, if not and you need it, then just add it back and change `nonlocal` to `global`.  That would reduce the closure to just an inner function.

Comment: although I'm not a massive fan of defining `change_variable` every time `function` is called, this does consolidate it, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this:

```
while 1:
        turtle.onkey(break, key)
```

is somewhat similar:

```
def outer(key):
    keep_going = True

    def quit_loop():
        nonlocal keep_going
        keep_going = False

    turtle.onkey(quit_loop, key)
    turtle.listen()
    while keep_going:
        turtle.left(70)
        turtle.forward(200)
    print("Done!")
```

Though probably not the short, easy solution you were hoping for!